# How to use views argument in drupal?

Tags: views

I am using views arguments for filtering jobs list.

I am taking state as argument.

Previously, state argument was accepting single value and it was filtering jobs correctly.

Now I made state field multivalued it means it accepts multiple states as input separated by comma.

here is my code for assigning arguments

```
$arg[0]=$filters['title_nodes'];
$arg[1]=$filters['company'];
$arg[2]=$filters['city'];
$arg[3]=$filters['state'];
$arg[4]=$filters['zip'];
$arg[5]=$filters['types'];
$arg[6]=$filters['categories'];
$arg[7]=$filters['industries'];
$arg[8]=$filters['beverages'];
$arg[9]=$filters['user'];
```

previously, `$arg[3]=$filters['state'];` this `$arg[3]` is filled with single state as New York etc. and for single value filter was working fine.

now, `$arg[3]=$filters['state'];` this argument is containing multiple states.

because of multiple states jobs are not getting filtered.

now suppose we entered 3 states, then in `$arg[3]`  3 states get stored and for each job,

argument checks whether there is any job who is having all 3 states in single job which is not possible.

Now how can I make this filter works for multiple states??

Thanks in advance.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a contextual filter, you can specify `AND` or `OR` logic for the multi-values.

Views says:

> Allow multiple values
>
> If selected, users can enter multiple values in the form of 1+2+3 (for
>   OR) or 1,2,3 (for AND).

So your querstring would have `&state=CA+NY+TX` to `OR` California, New York, and Texas states.